# In a working jqGrid with subGrid how I can hide the column where appears the plus/minus/open icons completely?

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

I want hide it completely from the main grid too.

See image for more clarification.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The column which you need to hide has the name `"subgrid"`. So to hide it you can use

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("hideCol", "subgrid");
```

If you need to implement interface for opening or closing subgrids you can call [toggleSubGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#methods) method directly. For example the following callback will toggle subgrid on double-click on the main row:

```js
ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    $(this).jqGrid("toggleSubGridRow", rowid);
}
```

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subgridtoggleondoubleclick.htm):

[image]

**UPDATED**: If you want to hide additionally the icon from the first column of subgrid you can use the option

```js
subGridOptions: { openicon: "ui-helper-hidden" }
```

and add additional CSS style

```css
.subgrid-cell .ui-helper-hidden { display: none}
```

See [the updated demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subgridtoggleondoubleclick1.htm):

[image]

**UPDATED 2**: To hide the column with the icon in the subgrid row you can just use

```css
.subgrid-cell { display: none}
```

See [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subgridtoggleondoubleclick2.htm):

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleg! I hoped so much that you will be online to answer me :D Thanks!! It worked in the main grid like a charm but I'm not been able to make this work in the subgrid, can you help me a little more? :D Thanks in advance!

Comment: The thing is that I want remove the subgrid icon column too. The only way I managed to do that is through `.subgrid-cell->display:none`, but then it shifts subgrid to the left one column (great! desired effect) but leaves a blank column at the right of subgrid (undesired effect). Instead of that black column I need that the subgrid expands and takes the whole width. Thanks again for the troubles :D

Comment: Thanks :) I think that I will let the subgrid as you shown in the second example, I still want to shift the subgrid one column to the left but that is fine :D Thanks again.

Comment: @diosney: If you need to hide the column with the icon you can just use CSS `.subgrid-cell { display: none}`: see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subgridtoggleondoubleclick2.htm)

Comment: Heyy! What you did in the last example is EXACTLY what I need! Thanks! I will check it and I will tell you later :D

Comment: Sorry, right now it is when I realizzed that I don't tell you an important data and it is that I'm using a Grid as a Subgrid. Can you show me an example?

Comment: @diosney: Sorry, but I am now in the business trip in another country. So I can't make more demos for you. I think that all what I posted should work also with Grid as a Subgrid. Which problem you have currently?

Comment: Oh! Sorry then :) It keep me showing a blank column at the right os the subgrid.

Comment: @diosney: I am not sure what is your problem. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/subgridswithdisabled.htm). Everything seems be OK. Probably you should increase the width of the column in the subgrid to have no free space?

Comment: Thanks, settings a width and autowidth=false solved my issue :D Thanks again :D