# jqGrid hidden plus/minus/open icon column make subgrid less wide as main row

Tags: jqgrid, width, hidden, subgrid

Following to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439147/in-a-working-jqgrid-with-subgrid-how-i-can-hide-the-column-where-appears-the-plu) about hiding plus/minus/open icon column, I have applied these suggests, so in CSS file :

```
.subgrid-cell { display: none; }
```

All is OK :

[image]

but the subgrid don't fill the width of right column of main grid.
[image]

Please, is there a mistake in my code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var OldSelectedRow=null;
var height=$('body').height()-210;
var numRows=Math.floor(height/23)-(Math.floor(height/23)%5);
var heightRows=numRows*23;
var myGrid = $("#tab22");
myGrid.jqGrid({
    caption:"Recherche d'un ARTICLE dans les PARCS CLIENTS",
    hidegrid:false,
    url:'sub22.php',
    datatype: "json",
    height:heightRows,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rowNum:numRows,
    rownumbers:true,
    rownumWidth: 40, 
    gridview: true,
    colNames:['Id','Code', 'Désignation', 'Famille','S/famille','Marque','Matière','Réf.constructeur','PV base'],
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"right",hidden:true}, 
        {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:150}, 
        {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr', width:200}, 
        {name:'f.code',index:'f.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'s.code',index:'s.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'k.code',index:'k.code', width:80}, 
        {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80},
        {name:'a.refc',index:'a.refc', width:150},
        {name:'t.pnc',index:'t.pnc', width:80, align:"right"}
    ], 
    pager: '#tab22p', 
    sortname: 'a.code', 
    sortorder: "asc", 
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',        
    altRows:true,
    altclass:'myAltRowClass',
    onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
        //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
        if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                        && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
        }
        $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
    },
    gridComplete:function(){
        OldSelectedRow=null;
        colModel = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
        sortName = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
        $('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID(myGrid[0].id) +
                ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;
                if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({cursor: 'default'});
                }
                if (cmi.name === sortName) {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                        //alert(i);
                        var gridId = myGrid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        for (var countRow = 0; countRow < gridId .length; countRow ++)
                        {
                            var rowId = gridId [countRow ];
                            var dataFromTheRow = myGrid.jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                            myGrid.jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '','ui-widget-header');
                            myGrid.jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '',{'border-top':0,'border-left':0});
                        }
                }
        });
    },
    onSelectRow:function(id,status){
        if(OldSelectedRow!=id){
            if(OldSelectedRow!=null){
                myGrid.jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', OldSelectedRow);
                $('#tab22_'+OldSelectedRow+'_t').remove();
                $('#'+OldSelectedRow).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            }
            $('#'+id).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            OldSelectedRow=id;
            myGrid.jqGrid('expandSubGridRow',id);
        }else{
                myGrid.jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', id);
                $('#tab22'+id+'_t').remove();
                $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                OldSelectedRow=null;
        }
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) { 
        rowdata = $("#tab22").jqGrid('getRowData',row_id);
        var art=rowdata['a.id'],lastId;
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t"; 
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id; 
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({ 
            url:"sg22.php?id="+row_id+"&art="+art, 
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ['Id','Groupe','Client', 'Nom','Ville','Matériel','Marque','Machine','Série','Type','Modèle','Désignation','N° série'],
            colModel: [ 
                {name:'p.id',index:'p.id', width:60, align:"right",hidden:true}, 
                {name:'g.code',index:'g.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:60},
                {name:'c.descr',index:'c.descr', width:200}, 
                {name:'c.ville',index:'c.ville', width:200}, 
                {name:'q.code',index:'q.code',width:80},
                {name:'k.code',index:'k.code', width:80}, 
                {name:'2h.code',index:'2h.code', width:60}, 
                {name:'2s.code',index:'2s.code', width:60}, 
                {name:'2t.code',index:'2t.code', width:60}, 
                {name:'2m.code',index:'2m.code', width:60}, 
                {name:'2m.descr',index:'2m.descr', width:200}, 
                {name:'p.numserie',index:'p.numserie', width:80}
            ], 
            pager: pager_id, 
            rownumbers: true,
            rowNum:15,
            rowNumWidth:40,             
            viewrecords: true,
            emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',    
            caption:"Liste des PARCS CLIENTS contenant l'ARTICLE sélectionné",
            hidegrid:false,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            autowidth:true,     
            altRows:true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            sortname: 'c.code', 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            height: 345,
            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                }
                $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
            },
            onSelectRow:function(id,status){
                if(lastId!=id){
                    if(lastId!=null){
                        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', lastId);
                        $('#'+subgrid_table_id+'t').remove();
                        $('#'+id).removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                    }
                    $('#'+id).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
                }
                lastId=id;
                $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('expandSubGridRow',id);
            },
            gridComplete:function(){
                //  montre la colonne triée au chargement des données
                colModel = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                sortName = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
                $('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID($("#"+subgrid_table_id)[0].id) +
                        ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                        var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;
                        if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                                $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                        } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                                $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({cursor: 'default'});
                        }
                        if (cmi.name === sortName) {
                                $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                                var gridId = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                for (var countRow = 0; countRow < gridId .length; countRow ++)
                                {
                                    var rowId = gridId [countRow ];
                                    var dataFromTheRow = $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                                    $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '','ui-widget-header');
                                    $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '',{'border-top':0,'border-left':0});
                                }
                        }
                });
            },
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid2_id, row2_id) { 
                rowdata = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData',row2_id);
                var parc=rowdata['p.id'],lastId=null;
                var subgrid2_table_id, pager2_id; 
                subgrid2_table_id = subgrid2_id+"_tt"; 
                pager2_id = "p_"+subgrid2_table_id; 
                $("#"+subgrid2_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid2_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager2_id+"' class='scroll'></div>"); 
                $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid({ 
                    url:"sg22b.php?id="+row2_id+"&parc="+parc, 
                    datatype: "json",
                    caption:"Détail du PARC",
                    hidegrid:false,
                    colNames:['Id','Ensemble','Article', 'Désignation', 'Famille','S/Famille','Matière','PV base','% Remise','PV net'],
                    colModel:[ 
                        {name:'a.id',index:'a.id', width:60, align:"right",hidden:true}, 
                        {name:'c.code',index:'c.code', width:100,sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'a.code',index:'a.code', width:100,sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'a.descr',index:'a.descr', width:400,sortable:false}, 
                        {name:'f.code',index:'f.code', width:80,sortable:false},
                        {name:'s.code',index:'s.code', width:80,sortable:false},
                        {name:'m.code',index:'m.code', width:80,sortable:false},
                        {name:'t.pnc',index:'t.pnc', width:80,align:'right',sortable:false},
                        {name:'rem',index:'rem', width:80,align:'center',sortable:false},
                        {name:'pv',index:'pv', width:80,align:'right',sortable:false}
                    ], 
                    pager: pager2_id, 
                    rownumbers: true, 
                    viewrecords: true,
                    emptyrecords: 'Aucune donnée correspondante...',        
                    rownumWidth: 40, 
                    altRows:true,
                    altclass:'myAltRowClass',
                    sortname: 'c.code', 
                    sortorder: "asc", 
                    scroll:true,
                    maxheight: 230,
                    onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                        //  montre la colonne sélectionnée pour le tri de la grille
                        if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                                        && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                                $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                                $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                        }
                        $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).addClass('ui-state-active');
                    },
                    gridComplete:function(){
                        //  montre la colonne triée au chargement des données
                        colModel = $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                        sortName = $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
                        $('#gbox_' + $.jgrid.jqID($("#"+subgrid2_table_id)[0].id) +
                                ' tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column').each(function (i) {
                                var cmi = colModel[i], colName = cmi.name;
                                if (cmi.sortable !== false) {
                                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico').show();
                                } else if (!cmi.sortable && colName !== 'rn' && colName !== 'cb' && colName !== 'subgrid') {
                                        $(this).find('>div.ui-jqgrid-sortable').css({cursor: 'default'});
                                }
                                if (cmi.name === sortName) {
                                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
                                        var gridId = $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                        for (var countRow = 0; countRow < gridId .length; countRow ++)
                                        {
                                            var rowId = gridId [countRow ];
                                            var dataFromTheRow = $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
                                            $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '','ui-widget-header');
                                            $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('setCell',rowId, i, '',{'border-top':0,'border-left':0});
                                        }
                                }
                        });
                    }
                })
                $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager2_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
                $("#"+subgrid2_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
            }
        }); 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false});
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid');
    },
    subGridRowColapsed: function(subgrid_id, row_id) { 
        // this function is called before removing the data 
        var subgrid_table_id; 
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t"; 
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).remove();
        myGrid.jqGrid('resetSelection');            
    }
});
myGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#tab22p',{search:false,del:false,edit:false,add:false});   
myGrid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
myGrid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
        .children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar")
        .css({
            textAlign: "center"
        })
        .children("span.ui-jqgrid-title")
        .css({
            float: "none",
            color:'red',
            fontSize:'16px'
        });
myGrid.jqGrid('hideCol', 'subgrid');
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
        myGrid.jqGrid('setGridWidth',$('body').width()-22);
        var height=$('body').height()-210;
        numRows=Math.floor(height/23)-(Math.floor(height/23)%5);
        heightRows=numRows*23;
        myGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {height:heightRows,rowNum:numRows});
        myGrid.jqGrid('setGridHeight',heightRows);
        myGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
}).trigger('resize');});
```

or is there some way to solve or turnaround this trouble ?

Many thanks to whose who could bring me some help. have a nice day

JiheL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct your question you can fix the problem by adding

```js
autowidth: true
```

option to **both** subgrids (see two callbacks `subGridRowExpanded` which you use).

I recommend you additionally to verify your code with respect of tools like JSLint or JSHint. You would see that your code use many undefined variables (`colModel`, `sortName`, `rowdata`). Additionally it's strictly recommended to use `idPrefix` option in jqGrid with subgrids to prevent possible id duplicates.

**UPDATED**: After you posted [the fiddler demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jihel/Cs9CP/10/) I understand the problem. To fix it I suggest to set `colspan` attribute on the `<td>` having `subgrid-data` class. For example one can include in `subGridRowExpanded` callback the line

```js
$("#" + subgrid_id).closest("td").attr("colspan", 3);
```

in your demo to fix the problem. See  http://jsfiddle.net/Cs9CP/11/ (or [the full screen demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs9CP/11/embedded/result/)). Additionally I recommend to use `height: "auto"` for all subgrids. As the result you will see something like

[image]

If you want you can additionally hide the first empty column in the subgrid with the line

```js
$("#  + subgrid_id).closest(".ui-subgrid").find("td[colspan=1]").first().hide();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Cs9CP/12/ (or [the full screen demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs9CP/12/embedded/result/)):

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your appreciate help and suggests ! I didn't know JSLint or JSHint very cool to spy wrong coding, tnaht you.

Comment: @JiheL: You are welcome! It's important to set some options (like "messy white space" and "many var statements per function") in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) especially at the beginning to discard unneeded "errors" and warnings and see really clear errors. What about your main problem? Do you have any progress?

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this question, and thank you for your help. I have added autowidth on second subgrid, as it was already on first, but no more change. Now, with JSHint my code seems less buggy, thank you. JiheL

Comment: @JiheL: Could you provide some test page where one could see and debug the problem? You can use `datatype: local` and `data: someArrayWithData` for example with some fix test data. If one would be able to debug the page which use non-minimized jqGrid (`jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) one could quickly find the reson of the problem and the way to solve it.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have made all suggested changes and prepared it for uploading on JSFiddle you could see on http://jsfiddle.net/jihel/Cs9CP/10/. The alert boxes are for my trouble with selrow which change and cancel edit operation. Please tell me if something is wrong, it's the first time I use this kind of tool. Many thanks for all time you spend for helpin me. JiheL

Comment: @JiheL: Demo is always good to analyse the problem. In **UPDATED** part of my answer I describe how to fix the problem. Additionally I recommentd you define *common* callback (like `onSortCol`) and common options (`altclass`, `rownumbers`, ...) in `$.jgrid.defaults`. In the way you can reduce and your code and simplify it maintain. You can additionally remove unneeded hidden `name:'id'` column from the grid. `id` attribute on `<tr>` save the same information.

Comment: Hello Oleg many many thanks for your great help you rocks ! As one goes along you answer to me I am learning more and more about jqGrid. Probably I will ask some other questions but I want really show you my gratitude for your kind help. Sorry for all time you spend. Best regards. JiheL