# It's possible to remove the expand/collapse column from the jqGrid header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the jqGrid available at http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and I can't find a way to disable its expand/collapse button on the top right of the header. Anyone know if there's an option to do that?

[image]
I tried jQuery("#list13").hideCol('subgrid');
but it does not work and made it worst.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need adjust additionally the value of [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) attribute of `td.subgrid-data` which hold the main information of subgrid. The structure of the subgrid row you can see on the picture below

[image]

I answered already on very close question. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15942850/315935) you should find all information and demos needed to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the main grids toggle button then you can set

```
hidegrid: false
```

If you are trying to disable or hide the subgrids expand and collapse button then use this on loadcomplete

```
jQuery("#GridTeableID").jqGrid('hideCol', "subgrid");
```